# Remove element from unordered_map without calling destructor on it

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I want to remove an element from an STDL unordered map without a destructor being called on that element. For example, say I have the following:

```
std::unordered_map<size_t, my_obj*> map;

my_obj *ptr = new my_obj();
map[5] = ptr;

map.erase(5); // This calls a destructor on ptr.
```

Is there a way for me to remove the entry `5 -> ptr` from the map, without calling the destructor of the element I'm removing?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: The destructor won't be called in that scnario anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The documentation seems to suggest otherwise: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/erase/

Comment: So...are those docs just completely wrong?

Comment: You have a pointer. Destructor won't be called. You misinterpreted the docs.

Comment: There is no destructor for a pointer. Your map contains pointers. If it contained objects, their destructor will be called. But your map doesn't contain objects. It contains pointers.

Comment: I see. Thanks everyone. Sorry for the ambiguous question.

Comment: To be more accurate, what's erased will be destroyed, but what's erased is a pointer so all that's destroyed is the pointer itself, not what it points at.

Comment: If you write your house address on a notepad, then destroy the notepad, the house is unaffected by that destruction.

Answer (score 1):

first get the key value pair in form of `std::pair` by:

```
std::unordered_map<int,my_obj*>::iterator Itr= map.find(5);
```

and then delete the ***value part*** of Itr which actually contains the pointer of `my_obj` as below to avoid memory leaks:

```
if(Itr not_eq map.end()) 
{
     delete Itr->second;
     Itr->second = nullptr;
     objects.erase(Itr);
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what’s being asked (although that’s a bit understandable since what’s being asked is already backwards).