# Does `unordered_map::erase()` always call the destructor immediately?

Tags: c++, destructor, unordered-map

Say I have `std::unordered_map<int, Foo> myMap;`. If I call `myMap.erase(1);`, will `Foo`'s destructor always be called immediately? Or is the standard library allowed to hang on that instance of `Foo` for as long as it wants, and maybe reuse it later?

(I understand that everything will always be properly destructed in the end, when the map itself is destroyed.)

Comment: We do not have garbage collection. After you call `erase()`, the lifetime of both key and value has ended and both destructors were called.

Comment: Possibly worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605945/remove-element-from-unordered-map-without-calling-destructor-on-it

Comment: *Or is the standard library allowed to hang on that instance of Foo for as long as it wants* -- C++ doesn't work this way.  C++ has deterministic destruction, unlike other languages that rely on garbage collection.

Comment: It is not just a matter of garbage collector or deterministic destruction. The question is legit as (theoretically) an implementation might only erase the value from the "logic" point of view. [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) technically says it removes the elements from the container. I think all not crazy implementations would call the destructor

Comment: "_Or is the standard library allowed to hang on that instance of Foo_": If you want an answer specifically about whether or not the standard makes any guarantees rather than what actual implementations do, then I would suggest adding the `language-lawyer` tag. Although the part "_will Foo's destructor always be called immediately_" should be easy to answer since a destructor call should be part of erasing the element in my opinion. But I suppose maybe the implementation may potentially hold on to a copy. I think the answer isn't trivial in that case.

Comment: @BiagioF I'm quite sure it's not "all not crazy implementations", it's "all conforming implementations". Although I haven't found definition for "erase" in standard, the `Cpp17Erasable from X` requirements requires that `allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p)` is well formed, and following the rabbit hole you end up at calling destructor.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: it has to be destroyed *eventually*, but it doesn't seem to have to be destroyed within the method directly

Comment: Some things I think you should read [object lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime), [scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) and then this might be useful too [introduction to smart pointers and move semantics](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-smart-pointers-move-semantics/)

Comment: If you are looking for loopholes, a `std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` can have other federated owners of the Foo via the shared pointer.  The map will destruct (*erase*) it's shared_ptr object, and if that's the last shared pointer then it will destruct the Foo.  (The memory may or may not be freed, depending if there are weak pointers around in which case the *control block* for the shared/weak pointer will stick around, and depending if the control block and the Foo were allocated together or separate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went over https://eel.is/c++draft/#containers, and it appears that it's not actually required.  Destroying the map, and copy or move *into* a container require that elements be destroyed, but the only mutating method I see that explicitly requires *destruction* is [`pop_back`](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements) and `pop_front`.

Theoretically, it appears that a map could contain an internal cache of "freed" nodes to reuse for future inserts, and it appears that it's not actually required to destroy and recreate the data itself if it does this. At least until the `map` destructor is called.

This is probably an oversight in the C++ spec, and I would be shocked if anyone implemented a map that didn't destroy and recreate the data though, even if they do cache nodes.

Comment: *"internal cache of "freed" nodes"* Hmm, one could call the element destructor but still preserve the node.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Right, the last paragraph says that that's what any sane caching implementation should do.

Comment: _Theoretically, it appears that a map could contain an internal cache of "freed" nodes to reuse for future inserts_ Does that contravene the 'as-if' rule?  I mean, `Foo`s destructor might close a file or something.

Comment: @PaulSanders: The as-if rule says what optimizations may do in an other way then the standard says. But in this case it seems not clear what the standard itself requires.

Comment: @PaulSanders: The standard says the destructor and `clear` has to destroy all elements, and that moving *to* and copy to has to reassign or destroy existing elements, and that `pop_front` and `pop_back` have to destroy.  But that's it. The spec doesn't say that other methods have to actually destroy (at least until the *container* destructor is called). Ergo no as-if rule applies :/